# "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage6" doesn't exist" Error

Tags: python, customtkinter

I want to have a button in appMain that opens app_settings and whenever i press the "settingsBtn"(at the end of the code) which should open this new window, i get this error. I am using customtkinter for the UI. I have tried putting the code in a class and calling it from there but still it did not work. Maybe i did something wrong. I just don't understand how to make this work properly. I have multiple buttons in appMain that i want them to do the same thing(open a new window).

```
appMain = ctk.CTk()

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("green")

appMain.title("FastPals")
appMain.geometry("1000x800")


def opensettings():
    app_settings = ctk.CTk()

    ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
    ctk.set_default_color_theme("green")

    app_settings.title("Settings")
    app_settings.geometry("800x600")

    # Frame for setting option with the buttons
    frame_settings = ctk.CTkFrame(master=app_settings, width=250, height=580, corner_radius=20, bg_color="transparent")
    frame_settings.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
    frame_settings.place(relx=0.17, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    go_back_btn = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_settings,
                                text="",
                                image=GoBackPic,
                                width=70,
                                height=30)
    go_back_btn.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.05, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    profile_setting = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_settings,
                                    text="Profile",
                                    height=30,
                                    image=ProfilePic)
    profile_setting.place(relx=0.655, rely=0.05, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    privacy_setting = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_settings,
                                    text="Privacy",
                                    width=220,
                                    height=30,
                                    image=PrivacyPic)
    privacy_setting.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.13, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    password_setting = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_settings,
                                     text="Password",
                                     width=220,
                                     height=30,
                                     image=PasswordPic)
    password_setting.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.21, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    preferences_setting = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_settings,
                                        text="Preferences",
                                        width=220,
                                        height=30,
                                        image=PreferencesPic)
    preferences_setting.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.29, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    setting5 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_settings,
                             text="Setting 5",
                             width=220,
                             height=30)
    setting5.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.37, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    setting6 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_settings,
                             text="Setting 6",
                             width=220,
                             height=30)
    setting6.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    setting7 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_settings,
                             text="Setting 7",
                             width=220,
                             height=30)
    setting7.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.53, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    setting8 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_settings,
                             text="Setting 8",
                             width=220,
                             height=30)
    setting8.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.61, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    # Frame for settings for the chosen option
    frame_settings = ctk.CTkFrame(master=app_settings, width=500, height=580, corner_radius=20, bg_color="transparent")
    frame_settings.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
    frame_settings.place(relx=0.663, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    app_settings.mainloop()


# Settings, Profile and Log out button
settingsBtn = ctk.CTkButton(master=appMain, text="Settings", image=SettingsPic, width=30, text_color="black",
                            command=opensettings)
```

If i understand correctly, i have this problem because i have two ctk.Ctk() in the code but i don't know how to fix it.

Full traceback error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\crist\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "C:\Users\crist\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 29, in opensettings
    go_back_btn = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_settings,
  File "C:\Users\crist\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 106, in __init__
    self._draw()
  File "C:\Users\crist\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 264, in _draw
    self._update_image()  # set image
  File "C:\Users\crist\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 173, in _update_image
    self._image_label.configure(image=self._image.create_scaled_photo_image(self._get_widget_scaling(),
  File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage6" doesn't exist
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: added the traceback too

Comment: Where did you define ```GoBackPic```?

Comment: i have it in a different .py file and i imported it in this one